Venv does not work? After activating Venv the installed packages are not found. Python interpreter problems?
So to explain: I have a folder with my venv's in it. Additionally I have installed python via Brew.
Weirdly enough I was running into issues where I couldn't install packages on the newest version of my Python, and no libraries are installed globally. So I decided to go around this mess with Venv's. So I installed my using packaging.python.org as a reference. I am now able to activate my venv with source "my cool path". And then I am able to install all the packages via pip I need. Asking it "where python" it indicates it's in the pip folder as it should.
Now my projects are in another folder, I open them via VSCode, use the command window in VSCode to activate the venv, but it doesn't find any of the installed packages. Using Python: Select Interpreter, I see that it's using the global interpreter, I can choose the venv path and the interpreter in there, but that just links to the global one...
What am I doing wrong?
I tried to activate the Venv in the actual Terminal from which VS runs the code. Tried installing a new venv using the aforementioned tutorial...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Make sure you have the Python extension installed. Do CMD+SHIFT+P to bring up the command palette.
Choose "Python: Select Interpreter".
And then choose where your python binary is.
Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments Half way down the page.

Thanks for the quick answer, so I have already done that. I click on choose path because it doesn't show up there. If I then go into the folder of the venv I can choose the file named python, which is in the bin. BUT this is apparently just an alias.

If I now choose the pyvenv.cfg file in the root, I get an error. But I think that that is the wrong file. But I do think this is the problem, since I choose the python alias, which just redirects to the global installation, so I call up the global installation via the venv??
